# How to fix 'Install failed. Installation failed <a href='rerun'>Rerun</a>' error in Android?

Tags: java, android, uart, android-things

I'm trying to connect a device (an oximeter) to a Android smartphone via UART cable. So I need to build an app capable of reading data from this device. For this, I'm using Android Things, but I haven't been able to make this app to run, 'cause I get this error: "Install failed.
Installation failed
Rerun"

Pretty sure this tag "uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things" android:required="true"" is getting me this error, without it it runs but crashes.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String TAG = "Log";

private static final String UART_DEVICE_NAME = null;

private UartDevice mDevice;

private TextView tv;
private List<String> serial;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    tv = findViewById(R.id.serial);
    serial = new ArrayList<>();

    PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
    List<String> deviceList = manager.getUartDeviceList();
    if (deviceList.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "No UART port available on this device.");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "List of available devices: " + deviceList);
    }

    // Attempt to access the UART device
    try {
        mDevice = manager.openUartDevice(deviceList.get(0));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to access UART device", e);
    }
    try {
        setFlowControlEnabled(mDevice, false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        configureUartFrame(mDevice);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        writeUartData(mDevice);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mDevice != null) {
        try {
            mDevice.close();
            mDevice = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to close UART device", e);
        }
    }
}

public void configureUartFrame(UartDevice uart) throws IOException {
    // Configure the UART port
    uart.setBaudrate(57600);
    uart.setDataSize(8);
    uart.setParity(UartDevice.PARITY_NONE);
    uart.setStopBits(1);
}

public void setFlowControlEnabled(UartDevice uart, boolean enable) throws 
IOException {
        uart.setHardwareFlowControl(UartDevice.HW_FLOW_CONTROL_NONE);
}

public void writeUartData(UartDevice uart) throws IOException {
    byte[] raw = new byte[]{(byte) 0xA5, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 
0x1A, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};
    byte cs = (byte) ((raw[1] ^ raw[2] ^ raw[3] ^ raw[4]) & 0xFF);
    raw[5] = cs;
    int count = uart.write(raw, raw.length);
    Log.d(TAG, "Wrote " + count + " bytes to peripheral");
    readUartBuffer(uart);
}

public void readUartBuffer(UartDevice uart) throws IOException {
    // Maximum amount of data to read at one time
    final int maxCount = 9600;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[maxCount];

    int count;
    while ((count = uart.read(buffer, buffer.length)) > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Read " + count + " bytes from peripheral");
        serial.add(String.valueOf(buffer[count]) + " ");
    }
    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < serial.size(); i++) {
        data.append(serial.get(i));
    }
    tv.setText(data);
}
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.oximetro">

<uses-permission 
android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things" 
android:required="true"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

build.Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.oximetro"
    minSdkVersion 27
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:+'
}
```

I appreciate any help, even alternatives to do what I'm trying to do, which is reading data from an oximeter via UART with an Android smartphone. Running this code I get the error mentioned above, so the app does not even open on device.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the Android Things library on your phone. Your phone doesn't have the library hooks to make the hardware connections. The phone, knowing it doesn't have everything it needs to run the app, should refuse the installation.

Comment: Thanks for this info. But where should I run this then? Is it imposible to run on my phone? What would be an alternative for reading data from the device to Android smartphone?

Comment: You can't run this on your phone. You'd need to use an Android Things-compatible device, or use some other hardware device which can communicate with your phone over a wireless protocol or through the cloud.

Comment: @ALEXANDRECHAGASVIEIRAJUNIOR If you are connecting your device to an Android phone, use the Android USB APIs to access that device: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb